# catch exception of serilog sink

Tags: asp.net, exception, mqtt, serilog, serilog-aspnetcore

Im trying to catch an exception in an asp.net core app which seems to be not directly on application level. Im using serilog with `Serilog.AspNetCore` and an mqtt-sink:

```
  builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .WriteTo.MQTT(publisherOptions, "top/log", formatter: new RenderedCompactJsonFormatter()));
```

If the mqtt broker is not reachable at one point the mqtt-sink throws an Exception when logging. How could I catch this exception for handling? Since `Serilog.AspNetCore` is routing the asp.net logs I cannot just wrap my own logs with try and catch. Also the mqtt-sink is an external library. I tried to wrap the `app.Run()` command with try and catch but it is not working. Has anyone an idea what needs to be done?
Edit: The mqtt-sink library implements the emit function in the following way:

```
public async void Emit(LogEvent logEvent)
        {            
            var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            Formatter.Format(logEvent, stringWriter);

            var applicationMessage = ... //shortened
            
            await MqttClient.PublishAsync(applicationMessage);
        }
```

The awaited call to MqttClient.Async throws the exception.

Comment: might be worth it to clarify/expand a little. On what thread is the exception? Have you configured the Serilog selflog? In general, events get caputred on the writer thead and buffered in the sink. Obv the Sink can have problems sending the events, but that should not be something you have try/catches for (coz its a different thread). (I know zero about he MQTT sink specifically but thats how all other sinks work in principle)

Comment: Hi Ruben, Thanks for the reply. I edited the question. I don't know on which thread the sink is running. As far as I can see it is a standard implementation of the ILogEventSink interface. But the app exits with exit code 134 :

`Unhandled exception. MQTTnet.Exceptions.MqttCommunicationException: The client is not connected.
   at MQTTnet.Client.MqttClient.ThrowIfNotConnected()
   at MQTTnet.Client.MqttClient.PublishAsync(MqttApplicationMessage applicationMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)`

Comment: I know what you mean. Usually serilog is configured to catch sink exceptions and write to selflog. But in my case this is not happening. Could this be because emit is an async function. The complete error stack continues like this 
 `at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__128_1(Object state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()`

Comment: if you point the file sink at a bad path, it wont tear down your app. Or point the Seq one at a bad URL, it won't either. It's a key assumption in Serilog to first do no harm - sounds like the sink is not doing the right thing. Better to research that in the MQTT sink's repo though. But that sink impl looks very naive - I'd compare with the impl pf the File sink and/or any other reasonably high downloads one